# Paw App - Can I use different headers for each part of a multipart body

Tags: paw-app

See title.  I have a multi-part body and want each part to have different headers.  Is this possible in Paw?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible with Paw yet.

*Note: a few users have asked that in the past, so we will consider adding this feature in a later release…*

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick reply.  Some popular APIs that use multi-part bodies require different headers (such as DocuSign's API), so it would be great if you could add this.