# Specify Content Type For Each Part Of A Multipart Form Request

Tags: multipartform-data, paw-app

I would like to be able to specify the content type for each part of a multipart form request individually, as specified by RFC 2388 section 3. (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt)

For example, in cURL, one can invoke the command

curl -v -X POST http://myserver.com/v1/form-data
-F 'request={"hello":"world"};type=application/json'

It was noted last year that many people have requested this, and the feature would be considered for implementation in a future release:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38529839/4521962

Please reconsider this feature request, as it is a requirement for a number of contemporary REST API's.